# Scss selector for two classes on the same item

Tags: css, sass

There is piece of code:

```
.number__icon-container {
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
   border-bottom: 1px solid;
   padding-left: 8rem;
   border-color: black.

   &_error  {
      border-color: red;
   }
}
```

If there is some div with `number__icon-container_error` class it will have red border color but it's not good for me. I need setup red border color for div if it has `number__icon-container_error` and `number__icon-container_focus` classes at the same time. How can I do it? Thanks!

Comment: Hello, 
You could use this selector `&_error#{&}_focus` instead of `&_error`.

Comment: @AmauryHanser That is the correct answer :) I've reopened the question because the duplicate actually points to the incorrect solution.

Comment: @Terry Hi. But do you think that it needs to be posted as an answer ?

Answer (score 7):

You want to get the selector :  `.number__icon-container_error.number__icon-container_focus` starting with this class `.number__icon-container`.

What you need is the **interpolation bracket** `#{}` because **two touching ampersands are invalid in Sass**.
[Here is an article on css-tricks.com](https://css-tricks.com/the-sass-ampersand/#article-header-id-11).

You can write:

```
  .number__icon-container {
    border-color: black;
      &_error#{&}_focus  { // See the use of the interpolation bracket ?
      border-color: red;
    }
  }
```

It will compile:

```
.number__icon-container {
  border-color: black;
}
.number__icon-container_error.number__icon-container_focus {
  border-color: red;
}
```